How to connect Sparrow with Bitcoin Core on Mac?
Trying to connect sparrow to core. Sparrow gives out this error
Could not connect:

Cannot find Bitcoin Core cookie file at [file path]

Everything was working fine until I toggled with sparrow incoming connections settings. I tried to look for a cookie file, it's not there.
All software is fresh. Please help. Using mac

Solved it!
Make sure you have "Enable RPC Server" enabled, or server "server": true in settings.json
